# SQL query to find the grouping

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a table  as follows

```
studentID Subject
   1       Sub1
   2       Sub1
   3       Sub1
   4       Sub1
   1       Sub2
   2       Sub2
   4       Sub2
   1       Sub3
   3       Sub3
   4       Sub3
```

I need to  group the students who has the same set of Subjects.Just need a give a unique group id to students with same set of subjects .

so here student id (1) and (4) will get say group id = 1

student id 2 - group id = 2(nobody else has only sub 1 and sub 2)

student id  3  - group id = 3

the result should be like

```
 studentid groupid
     1        1
     4        1
     2        2
     3        3
```

I have written a sqlquery which uses FORXML to group all subjects of a student to a single column then use a group by on that column and then associate a rank to them. Is there a better way to do this

Comment: Good question, this is not easy in SQL.  Creating a group description using `for xml` seems like a neat trick to solve this.

Comment: I think It's good way to solve this with grouping by concatenated Sub. You have to check that you have correct order of Subjects in concatenated string, though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one approach.

For each student, find all other students that have the same set of courses.  You can do this by using the following rules.  Two students have the same courses when (1) they each have the same number of courses; (2) the number of courses they have in common is the same as the number of courses.

The implementation uses ranking functions to find the number of courses and a join/group by to count the number in common for two different students.

After that, the group id is simply the minimum student id, among the pairs in this table.

```
select s1.StudentId, MIN(SameAsStudentId) as groupid
from (select s1.StudentId as StudentId, s2.StudentId as SameAsStudentId
      from (select ss.*, COUNT(*) over (studentId) as NumSubjects
            from ss
           ) s1 join
           (select ss.*, COUNT(*) over (studentId) as NumSubjects
            from ss
           ) s2
           where s1.Subject = s2.Subject
      group by s1.StudentId, s2.StudentId
      having s1.NumSubjects = s2.NumSubjects and
             COUNT(*) = s1.NumSubjects
     ) t
group by StudentId
```

If you want groupid that has no "holes", you can wrap an outer query that uses `dense_rank` to assign the group id.

Answer (score 0):

One way of handling this is to create a bitmask for the subjects. First assign distinct, arbitrary powers of two to each of the subjects:

```
Subject  Value
Sub1         1
Sub2         2
Sub3         4
```

Now you can sum each student's subject's values. Each combination of subjects will have a unique value. There is a caveat, in that if the number of subjects is too large, you might get a numeric overflow.

You can even do this in a single query:

```
Select StudentID, sum(Subject_Value)
from Student_Subjects ss join
     (select distinct subject, 
                      power(2,dense_rank() 
                              over (order by subject)-1) as Subject_Value 
      from Student_Subjects) sv 
  on ss.subject = sv.subject
group by StudentID
```